# angular2 rc.6 custom form validator form value not getting updated

Tags: angular

Please see this plunkr: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/jZLDynQjwgbuW4k8rG5s?p=preview

counter remains 3 since form control . value is not getting the updates
worked fine in rc.5

`export function createCounterRangeValidator(maxValue, minValue) {
  return (c: FormControl) => {
    let err = {
      rangeError: {
        given: c.value,
        max: maxValue || 10,
        min: minValue || 0
      }
    };
  alert(c.value)
  return (c.value > +maxValue || c.value < +minValue) ? err: null;
  }
}`

regards

Sean

Answer (score 0):

fix is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/bfYHY1tYcEuBknEIU37v?p=preview

via:

`set counterValue(val) {
        this._counterValue = val;
        this.propagateChange.forEach(fn => fn(val));
    }`